# Java-Recursion: When does statements after a recursive method call executes

Tags: java, data-structures, recursion

When are statements after the method call itself going to execute?

```
private void inorderHelper(TreeNode node)
{
    if ( node==null )
        return;
    inorderHelper(node.leftNode);
    System.out.printf("%d", node.data);
    inorderHelper(node.rigthNode);
}
```

All I can see is that the line of codes inorderHelper(node.leftNode) will continue to iterate until node == null and the method terminates immediately before node.data is printed. I think that I didn't get well recursion but all examples I can find doesn't have statements after the recursive call. All I want to know is when are statements like System.out.printf("%d",node.data) going to execute before the method return?

Comment: What i see is a compile error..

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be thinking in terms of a single activation of a method. In a recursive call situation the same method can be called many times. Each call has its own stack frame. A return only return from the activation in which it is called. When it returns, control is transferred back to the activation that called it, just as if it had been called by a different method.

The code after the recursive call runs, in each activation, immediately on return from the activation it called.

Comment: thank you very much.I got it clear now, what you thought that I was thinking is what i was really thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This function will recursively traverse the binary tree **until the left half is traversed**, and then print the **data** and then it will traverse the **right half** of the tree.

This is the same at **every level of the tree**, this means that you will see the left half of the tree printed, at any level, before the data is printed, followed by the right half.

This manner of processing is called **"In order Traversal"** as your function indicates, the other ways are **"Pre order traversal"**, where the data is printed first, and **"Post order traversal"** where the data is printed last. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_traversal_2) has more info.

To learn better, you can step through with a debugger.

As an analogy, think **[Inception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception)** except that **each dream gets paused** until the **inner dream finishes**. Another difference is that in Inception, the outer dream controls the termination of the inner dream, while in recursion, the outer calls need to wait until inner calls terminate, before they can continue.

Comment: thanks I get your point. But the question I think I have is that; looking at the flow of execution in my understanding the function passes through the left half but does not print data, which is not true because it does. so in that sens my question is how does this happen for the function to reach the statement that prints the data and the statement that go through the right half, if the statement that passes through the left half recursively will cause the function to terminate?

Comment: @RuruMorlano  The function is called multiple times by itself. This is the essense of recursion, On of these calls terminating does NOT imply all of them terminate, and is NOT even related to the other calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this, it should help you get a good picture.

```
// first call with depth 0
private void inorderHelper(TreeNode node, int depth)
{
  ++depth;
  if ( node==null ) {
    System.out.printf("null node at depth %d", depth);
    return;
  }
  System.out.printf("depth %d data %d before left side", depth, node.data);
  inorderHelper(node.leftNode, depth);
  System.out.printf("depth %d data %d middle", depth, node.data);
  inorderHelper(node.rigthNode, depth);
  System.out.printf("depth %d data %d after right side", depth, node.data);
}
```